# What is the best J2ME UI Library

Tags: user-interface, java-me

What's the J2ME UI library you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use [J2ME Polish](http://www.j2mepolish.org).

Along with [LWUIT](http://lwuit.java.net/) seem to be the best options. The reason why I'm using Polish instead of LWUIT is because supports CLDC 1.0 and LWUIT doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Lot of UI framework [available](http://javabyexample.wisdomplug.com/component/content/article/44/73.html) for developing j2me application. But i suggest [LWUIT](https://lwuit.dev.java.net/) framework. LWUIT offers advanced UI capabilities and a clean API that is inspired by Swing. You can develop your own theme and animated screens by using LWUIT ResourceEdit. See the [LWUIT blog](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/).

You can download latest LWUIT from this [repository](https://lwuit.dev.java.net/source/browse/lwuit/) or you can use latest release of LWUIT version 1.4 [available](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/downloads/index.html). LWUIT supports Blackberry, Android and Symbian OS.

For more info see this links for your reference,

[Introduction of LWUIT](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javame/lwuit_intro/)

[Building theme for LWUIT](http://www.themeswiki.org/Building_themes_using_LWUIT)

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I was looking for a framework that supports CLDC 1.0 and LWUIT doesn't :(

Comment: Hmmmm. you are right. LWUIT never support. For this purpose you can use J2me polish. more info see this link, http://www.j2mepolish.org/cms/leftsection/documentation/platforms/midp.html

Answer (score 0):

I have used [LWUIT](https://lwuit.dev.java.net/) in a mobile application, even for BB devices, this framework was quite good. Also, AFAIK, it supports touch screen devices.

Also, it comes with a bundled toolkit, which helps you configure framework, animations, layouts, localization and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I was looking for a framework that supports CLDC 1.0 and LWUIT doesn't :(

Comment: Out of interest, why do you still need CLDC 1.0?  It's 2011 after all!  I'm all for supporting legacy devices where possible, but is this really necessary?

Comment: I understand your point of view and agree with it. What happens is that I'm currently developing a project that must be compatible with all mobiles that support java.